# Power BI - Table Matrix Different view

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

When you have Columns with two category (Columns_A and Columns_B)
And you have 2 measures (Value1 and Value2) (from different tables, but it doesnt matter)

Then normaly Table metrix shows like this:

[image]

But what I need is to switch columns with value in first 2 rows like this:
In other words, I need division of categories for every value.

[image]

All in One image (My dataset) :)

[image]

Do you have any idea please?

Maybe in python? (I guess)
Thanks

Comment: Please add some sample data with your required output.

Comment: mkRabbani, thank you for your answer. I updated my post. Please look at 3. image.

Answer (score 0):

Create a relationship b/w both the tables with Category column and then merge both the tables by following the steps in the screenshot. (Use full outer join while merging)
and then perform unpivot operation to see the below result set.

[image]

Now in the visualization tab select the matrix and as below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But my Cost and Profit Tables are more complex with different columns. And also they are too big for merge. Is there other solution? For example in python (i just guess)